# Reference request: Wasserstein metric spaces for non linear weights/mobility?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, optimal-transportation

There is a very nice theory of gradient flows in metric spaces by [Ambrosio, Gigli and Savaré](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-7643-8721-1). One particularly important application is the quadratic Wasserstein setting, where the metric space in question is $(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{W}_2)$, $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}(X)$ being the space of Borel probability measures on a polish space $X$ and $\mathcal{W}_2$ the associated quadratic [Wasserstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric). This theory has been succesfully applied in PDE's (see e.g Otto's [geometry of dissipative evolution equations](http://www.mis.mpg.de/preprints/1999/preprint1999_8.pdf)) and has deep connections with optimal mass transport.

In this particular context one uses continuity equations $\partial_t\mu_t+\operatorname{div}(\mu_t v_t)=0$ for measures $\mu\in \mathcal{P}(X)$ in order to formally view $\mathcal{P}$ as a Riemanian Manifold $\mathcal{M}$. The norm of a tangent vector $\dot{\mu_t}\in T_{\mu_t}\mathcal{M}$ can be defined as weigthed $L^2$
$$
|\dot{\mu}_t|_{T_{\mu_t}\mathcal{M}}^2=\int |v_t|^2d\mu_t.
$$
I apologize for not giving more details but this is a whole theory of its own.

Here is my question:

> Has anyone seen a similar theory with **non-linear weights**? More precisely: assume that one is only interested in measures $\mu=\rho(x)dx$ that are absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue's measure (say on a base space $X=\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ for simplicity), and that we are given a fixed "mobility function" $\eta:[0,\infty]\to [0,\infty]$ such that $\eta(0)=0$. Can one use nonlinear continuity equations $\partial_t\rho_t+\operatorname{div}(\eta(\rho_t)v_t)=0$ and weighted norms
>   $$
> |\dot{\mu}_t|_{\mu_t}^2\approx\int |v_t|^2\eta(\rho_t)dx
> $$
>   to build a similar "theory"? (or at least apply some ideas, I do not want to redo the whole theory)

This question arised in my research from a specific physical system with conservation of mass that enjoys a gradient-flow structure through an Energy-Dissipation-Inequality, but with a prescribed nonlinear mobility function as above. (see [[1](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-7643-8721-1)] for EDI formulations of gradient flows in metric spaces)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this issue has been considered. You can start having a look at `A new class of transport distances between measures' by Dolbeault,  Nazaret and Savaré (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00526-008-0182-5).

The basic assumption needed for the theory to work is that the mobility $\eta$ is increasing and concave, as discussed in the paper.